# Iterating through a list of paths from a config file?

Tags: c#, list, config

I have a console app with a few foreach loops that iterate through paths and parses out email addresses from csv files. However, I need my loop to read from a config file instead of going through the directory, then ultimately call an existing API endpoint for each email address. This is what I have now:

```
 static void RunTask(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string folders in Directory.EnumerateDirectories("C:\\tests"))//looks at every folder within this main folder called tests --this needs to read the list of paths
            {
                foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folders, "*.csv"))//looks at every file with the extension ".csv" in each folder
                {
                    Debug.Write("\n" + path + "\n"); //writes out file names
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
                    {
                        String line;

                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] parts = line.Split(',');

                            string email = parts[1];
                            Debug.Write(email + "\n");//writes out email column

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

This is what's in my Path.Config file:

```
<pathsSettings>
  <paths>
    <add Path="C:\tests\first" 
         TemplateId="123456">
    </add>
    <add Path="C:\tests\second"
         TemplateId="tem_56hyNijCXxGP52ZrgdWziC ">
    </add>
    <add Path="C:\tests\third"
         TemplateId="tem_2wWT6YfGkDXSntEPKhHCWB ">
    </add>
  </paths>
</pathsSettings>
```

I'm not sure how I should be writing my foreach to draw from a list of these paths.

Comment: Use XDocument / XElement to iterate over the XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class PathTemplate
 {
     public string path { get; set; }
     public string template { get; set; }
 }

  public static string getxml()
    {
        return "<pathsSettings>" +
               "<paths>" +
               "<add Path=\"C:\\tests\\first\" TemplateId=\"123456\"></add>" +
               "<add Path=\"C:\\tests\\second\" TemplateId=\"tem_56hyNijCXxGP52ZrgdWziC \"></add>" +
               "<add Path=\"C:\\tests\\third\" TemplateId=\"tem_2wWT6YfGkDXSntEPKhHCWB \"></add>" +
               "</paths>" +
               "</pathsSettings>";
    }


var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(getxml());

        Console.WriteLine(xdoc);

        var pts = xdoc.Elements("pathsSettings")
            .Elements("paths")
            .Elements("add").
            Select(p => new PathTemplate()
            {
                path = p.Attribute("Path").Value.ToString(),
                template = p.Attribute("TemplateId").Value.ToString()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.Value.ToString()` when `.Value` is already a `string`?

Comment: @Enigmativity, you are correct, .ToString() is redundant and not needed

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize the xml if you have your objects right.
I would say your classes should look as follows:

```
[Serializable()]
public class add
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("Path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("TemplateId")]
    public string TemplateId { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("pathsSettings")]
public class pathsSettings
{
    [XmlArray("paths")]
    [XmlArrayItem("add", typeof(add))]
    public add[] paths { get; set; }
}
```

And you could iterate over it like this

```
public void DoWhatever(){
        pathsSettings myObject;
        // Construct an instance of the XmlSerializer with the type
        // of object that is being deserialized.
        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(pathsSettings));
        // To read the file, create a FileStream.
        FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(@"yourpath\Path.config", FileMode.Open);
        // Call the Deserialize method and cast to the object type.
        myObject = (pathsSettings)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
        foreach(add addObj in myObject.paths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(addObj.Path);
            Console.WriteLine(addObj.TemplateId);
        }
}
```

This method requires that you have your objects right but in the long run you can use these objects to serialize your values, if needed, and so edit your config file. If you furthermore need your TemplateId then you have it already in your "add" Object

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<pathsSettings>
  <paths>
    <add Path=""C:\tests\first"" 
         TemplateId=""123456"">
    </add>
    <add Path=""C:\tests\second""
         TemplateId=""tem_56hyNijCXxGP52ZrgdWziC "">
    </add>
    <add Path=""C:\tests\third""
         TemplateId=""tem_2wWT6YfGkDXSntEPKhHCWB "">
    </add>
  </paths>
</pathsSettings>");

var paths =
    doc
        .Root
        .Descendants("add")
        .Select(e => e.Attribute("Path").Value)
        .ToList();
```

That gave me these paths in a list:

```
C:\tests\first 
C:\tests\second 
C:\tests\third
```